# Can I use PARSE for creating turned based Game?

Tags: game-design, ios, turn-based

I am working on creating a Turned - Based game similar to "Draw Something". I want to replace the Game Center feature with my own server using PARSE. Replace in terms of all game logic like Match making, Notifying Turns etc in PARSE Server. I have used PARSE to create app like similar to Instagram where user will have their account and they do stuff within. However I am wondering if I can put logic of match making in PARSE Server to get match for any of player. More of features of Game Center might needed to be build in PARSE Server.

Kindly let me know any suggestions if anyone has used PARSE as Game Server. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PARSE for gaming. I made proof-of-concept a while ago for a tic-tac-toe game. Things like push notifications to notify change of turns and things like that all worked nicely. I stored the turn delta's in PARSE to keep the amount of data going back and forth to a minimum (keeping in mind that not everyone is on a 4G+ or Wifi network in a mobile environment).

The only downside may be a long term one, the amount of requests etc. may outgrow the 'free' model so keep that in mind in pricing your game. Design your game to keep requests etc at a minimum. 
On the other hand, this rings true for any application where you need a centralized server, as a centralized server (physical or virtual) usually costs money if traffic becomes numerous.

Comment: It has been announced that PARSE will shut down. See blog post here: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/